# How to test a method within a class

Tags: apex, unit-test

I am fairly new to both unit testing and apex. I am trying to test a method within a class, but i keep getting an error which tells me method does not exist. I have a feeling that perhaps my syntax is incorrect, but in my previous test that i have created where I am doing something very similar. The syntax does in fact work properly which is where I am confused.

In my model `ApplicationContactMappingSettingModel` I have a the public method:

```
public List<FieldMap> getFieldMap(String category){
//code to throw exception in here
}
```

In my test class

```
static testMethod void test_get_field_map(){
   Application_Contact_Mapping_Settings__c acmSetting = ApplicationMappingTestDataUtils.createOneApplicationContactMappingSetting('string in here', true, 'another string');
ApplicationContactMappingSettingsModel scmSettingsModel = new ApplicationContactMappingSettingsModel();
}
```

When I try to get the public List from my class by writing this:

```
//in my model the class of FieldMap has these operators
scmSettingsModel.FieldMap('string','another string', 'another string')

List<FieldMap> category = scmSettingsModel.getFieldMap();
```

I get the error message telling me the method does not exist 
Does anyone know the proper way of calling this method? Please let me know if there is more information i can add to make this more helpful, Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You declare the method like this:

`public List<FieldMap> getFieldMap(String category)`

But you use it like this:

`List<FieldMap> category = scmSettingsModel.getFieldMap();`

Note that the method signatures do not match: the method accepts a string but you did not pass one in.

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your response. I'm not sure I follow...I must first declare the method within my test and then use it, but I must also supply a string within the ()?

Comment: Yes, you need to pass a string into the method. When the Apex compiler runs, it will see you gave it a string and find the correct method, and that error should go away. Right now it is looking for a method by the same name that accepts zero parameters, but cannot find it, which is why it gives you that error. This is called *method overloading* and works like most other modern languages such as Java, C#, and C++.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying, when i do this i get the error "Invalid type: FieldMap" Is there a special way to be calling a list that has a class in it?

Comment: That is the correct way, as long as `FieldMap` is a valid class. It must be, if the `ApplicationContactMappingSettingModel` class compiles.

Comment: hmm interesting. it is definitely a valid class

Comment: Apparently this is an inner class, I should be able to say the scmSettingsModel.FieldMap....however this does not work either

Comment: The inner class would be called `ApplicationContactMappingSettingsModel.FieldMap`.